# Set a class to prototype in NuxtJS Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

How to set a class to prototype correctly in Vue NuxtJS?

I create plugin

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/global.js" },
],
```

global.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import CustomStore from "devextreme/data/custom_store";

//try set in prototype
Vue.use(CustomStore)
```

have error

```
A class must be instantiated using the 'new'
```

I understand that this is not correct, but I can not find anywhere how to initialize it

```
Vue.use(new CustomStore());
```

no error but how call?

I want to use something like this in my component

```
this.dataSource = this.$CustomStore({ ///... settings...// })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `CustomStore` is a function, so you can try using Nuxt.js `inject()` method. This method will make your functions or values available across your app.

**~/plugins/global.js**

```js
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  // Inject $CustomStore() in Vue, context and store.
  inject('CustomStore', CustomStore)
}
```

then you can use it across your app components.

**your component**

```js
 mounted() {
   this.$CustomStore()
 },
```

reference https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context

Comment: yes i thought about this and the call works this.dataSourceOrg = new this.$CustomStore({     });